# Listing all SVN repositories

Tags: svn

In subversion is there a command to list all the available repositories registered on a particular host?

Eg. in ClearCase, a `cleartool lsvob` would give me the listing of all the versioned databases in a given region. I have not been able to find anything akin to this in subversion.

Comment: svn list <svn server path> works. As described in the url below - 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541577/listing-all-svn-repositories

Comment: @rajneesh, that command doesn't work for me. I'm using Visual SVN Server 1.9.4. Also, the URL you provided just links back to this question. (Not sure if someone's changed it since you posted that comment.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Each subversion repository is independent and knows nothing about the others. There would be no way to locate all of the subversion repositories.

We keep all of our repositories in a standard location (`/data/svn`) and can easily and programatically list all of the repositories:

```
ls /data/svn
```

Or from a remote system:

```
ssh svn ls /data/svn
```

Comment: OK thanks. We do the same here, but my question was pertaining to some legacy networks that I have on hand - and know nothing about regarding how it was setup etc., Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @BobC: Not really. Although that might be a viable way to accomplish something similar, it only works if all of your repositories are on one filesystem (and there's no reason they even have to use a filesystem). The real answer is you can't do it because repositories are independent - there is no such subversion command.

Answer (score 5):

SVN repos have a distinct structure (/conf, /hooks, /db, /locks), so searching for one if its components would be a start.

If locate/updatedb is installed and current:

```
locate /db | grep /db$
```

Or by an exhaustive search:

```
find / -type d | grep /db$
```

A more sophisticated search would check for the full set of components.

Answer (score 1):

You can create subversion repos anywhere on your server and they are not linked to each other.

In my server I put everything in /var/svn/ then I can list all the repository using ssh and listing this repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find -iname .svn
```

it should list all working directories on a host

Answer (score 0):

If the svn server is local,for Linux from shell use these commands

```
#ps aux|grep svnserve/media/Hitachi_boot_disk/Repositories
```

This will show you how the svn service was started.
It will look something like:

```
/usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /media/Hitachi_boot_disk/Repositories
```

The path following the -r specifies the path to all Repositories

```
#cd /media/Hitachi_boot_disk/Repositories
#ls
```

This will list all the repositories under this server

Answer (score 0):

If you relax the requirement to a smaller set of suspected directories, this command is useful for scripting to get the base directories of a bunch of svn repositories, but it's too slow for searching /.  If you need entire system I'd pursue BobC's solution.  This method works on repositories and not working copies.

`find <directories> -type d -exec bash -c 'if svnlook info "{}" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "{}"; fi' \;`